# Which language is used to design the 1990 photoshop?

Tags: pascal

http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57569533-93/adobe-releases-source-code-for-1990-version-of-photoshop/

http://www.computerhistory.org/atchm/photoshop-license-agreement/

Question> Is this pascal?

```
PROCEDURE AddCode (node: PNode; code: INTEGER; VAR word: Str255);

VAR
    branch: INTEGER;

BEGIN

IF LENGTH (word) = 0 THEN
    BEGIN

    IF node^.leaf OR (node^.branch [0] <> NIL) OR
                     (node^.branch [1] <> NIL) THEN
        BEGIN
        WRITELN ('? Conflict for code ', code:1);
        EXIT (PROGRAM)
        END;

    node^.leaf := TRUE;
    node^.code := code

    END

ELSE
    BEGIN

    IF word [1] = '0' THEN
        branch := 0
    ELSE IF word [1] = '1' THEN
        branch := 1
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        WRITELN ('? Invalid word for code ', code:1);
        EXIT (PROGRAM)
        END;

    DELETE (word, 1, 1);

    IF node^.branch [branch] = NIL THEN
        BEGIN

        NEW (node^.branch [branch]);

        node^.branch [branch]^.leaf := FALSE;
        node^.branch [branch]^.branch [0] := NIL;
        node^.branch [branch]^.branch [1] := NIL

        END;

    AddCode (node^.branch [branch], code, word)

    END

END;
```

Comment: Except for the "exit(program)" it could be turbo pascal even. But probably its Apple Pascal. Free Pascal supports it to some degree

Comment: This little code snippet reminds me why I used indented open/close braces when I first learned C, a habit that I soon outgrew. I always wondered why I did that. It looks so natural with BEGIN/END.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cnet article links to [a blog post from the Computer History Museum](http://www.computerhistory.org/adobe-ps-source/) announcing the release of the code, which tells you the answer:

> By line count, about 75% of the code is in Pascal, about 15% is in 68000 assembler language, and the rest is data of various sorts.

The particular code quoted in the question is indeed Pascal.